# Audible clicking at high speeds - what could it be?

Tags: ford, noise, mustang

I just recently started hearing an audible clicking sound in my 2015 Ford Mustang Ecoboost.

I only hear it in 3rd and 4th gear and only when I'm at about 3.5k rpm and higher. (I originally just thought my tires were kicking up rocks and it was hitting my car but then realized it was happening a lot).

I started using octane booster with my gas because I am stationed in Spain and not every gas station has premium fuel. I'm worried that this is a big issue and not sure if I can get warranty support here in Spain. The car has almost 26k miles on it.

Spain does not sell Mustangs so there is not much expertise here for the car. This mustang is a Roush edition and has the quad exhaust and a Roush cold air intake installed.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the click vary with engine speed or wheel speed?  Does it sound to be coming from the engine or suspension?

Comment: Since you said roush I'm assuming that you have the turbocharged 2,3L. Or is it the supercharged 5.0-liter V8? In the latter case I don't think it's really an Ecoboost. Which is it?

Comment: If it's the 4 cylinder, read this article, especially the paragraph starting with "Ford has been agonizing about the noise the EcoBoost Mustang makes."  http://www.caranddriver.com/reviews/2015-ford-mustang-23l-ecoboost-first-ride-review

Comment: Thanks for the resoonses... to clarify a couple things... I am not sure if it's coming from the engine or suspension, like I said I can only hear it at high rpm so I'm trying to listen for it while on the freeway with the window down.. hard to pinpoint where exactly the noise is coming from and also yes it is a roush 2.3l turbo ecoboost.

Comment: Noises have to be isolated to help understand. A rock in a tire, noise is a sound wave reflecting back to you somehow. Windows down difference etc. I had a lifted Toyota PU with a billion miles on it and an engine noise ended up being the need for a new engine but with so many noises I couldn't differentiate what clue I needed. The truck already had 2 prior motors and 3 transmissions, I should be a pro at this. When the rods push through an engine, it's too late. That was my 3 week vacation in Whitehorse BC Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've been able to figure it out, but on my Ecoboost Manual Transmission, the piece used to put the vehicle in Reverse on this shifter will rattle at high RPMs. If you put your hand on this, as if you were going to shift to reverse, when the rattle occurs it will go away (if that is the issue).

Answer (score 0):

So there is not a single similar sound in 1st and second? Also you say it happens in both 3rd and 4th. Clearly the exact same shifter and transmission are being used so we start looking to conditions changing at the time, right? 3rd and 4th suggest your car is traveling at a higher speed at that time thus more air flowing under the car etc. perhaps a loose bracket under a fender etc. under the stronger air flow is rattling but only with wind speed over 45 miles an hour or so. If this had not been a Rouch but a base Mustang I'd be asking if it has hub caps as some of them click when the plastic lug covers are loose.